# Jquery using the each iterator

Tags: jquery, html

I am appending data to a table using append. I would like to be able to delete each row I append one by one. However the way it's working now is it deletes all children.
What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/HjFPR/44/

```
<table class="" width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

<tr><th>Date</th><th>Pokemanz</th><th align="right" style="text-align:right;">Value</th></tr>



<tr><td style="width:62px;"><input type="text" 
class="transactions_date" size="15" value="4/5/12"/>
</td><td><input type="text" class="transaction_title" size="30" 
value="Pickachu"/></td><td align="right">
<input type="text" class="transactions_amount" size="10" value="$25"/></td></tr>

</table>
<div class="new_transaction"></div>
<input type="button"  value ="Add Transaction"  id="add_trans"/> 
<input type="button"  value ="Delete Transaction" id="delete_trans" />
```

​

```
(function() {

    $('#add_trans').on('click',function () {

        $('.new_transaction').append('<tr><td style="width:62px;"><input type="text" class="transactions_date" size="15" value=""/></td><td> <input type="text" class="transaction_title" size="30" value=""/></td><td align="right"><input type="text" class="transactions_amount" size="10" value=""/></td></tr>');


    });

    $('#delete_trans').on('click',function () {

    $('.new_transaction').children().each(function () {
    $(this).remove(); // "this" is the current element in the loop
});

    });

})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) in your jQuery:

```
$('#delete_trans').on('click',function () {
    $('.new_transaction tr').last().remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HjFPR/49/

Comment: But why would you iterate on a single element? A downvote from me.

Comment: I saw that after I posted it, I was updating my answer when you downvoted :)

Comment: Removed the downvote and upvoted. I also edited out the bad example so nobody will copy and paste it in a hurry. Bad code should not spread.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the last row, you'll want to use the jQuery [last](http://api.jquery.com/last/) selector.  And, given that, you don't need the each statement, so it is even simpler to do:

```
(function() {
    $('#add_trans').on('click',function () {
        $('.new_transaction').append('<tr><td style="width:62px;"><input type="text" class="transactions_date" size="15" value=""/></td><td> <input type="text" class="transaction_title" size="30" value=""/></td><td align="right"><input type="text" class="transactions_amount" size="10" value=""/></td></tr>');
    });

    $('#delete_trans').on('click',function () {
        $('.new_transaction tr').last().remove();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Description

There are several ways to delete the last children.

You can either use the `:last-child` selector or the `last()` method

### Samples

#### :last-child sample

```
$('#delete_trans').on('click',function () {
    $('.new_transaction').children(":last-child").remove();
});
```

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjFPR/46/)

#### last() sample

```
$('#delete_trans').on('click',function () {
    $('.new_transaction').children().last().remove();
});
```

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjFPR/47/)